# Intersection between two multivariate normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian

I have two multivariate normal distributions drawn from input data points. I am trying to generate a multivariate normal distribution, which can approximate the intersection of two input multivariate normal distributions. Is there any way to estimate mean and covariance of the intersection of two multivariate normal distributions?

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection of two normal distributions?

Comment: I meant overlapping area of two multivariate normal distributions